# In-accessible due to protection Level error in asp.net-C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have two classes 'passwordsettings' and 'helper'.The classes are given.

Passwordsettings.cs

```
public class PasswordSetting
{
    public PasswordSetting()
    {

    }

    //password age , 80, 180, 360 days
    public int Duration { get; set; }

    //password minimum length
    public int MinLength { get; set; }

    //password maximum length
    public int MaxLength { get; set; }

    //password Numbers length
    public int NumsLength { get; set; }

    //password Upper letter length
    public int UpperLength { get; set; }

    //password Special character length
    public int SpecialLength { get; set; }

    //password valid special characters
    public string SpecialChars { get; set; }
}
```

Helper.cs

```
public  class Helper
{
    public Helper()
    {        
         //TODO: Add constructor logic here        
    }

    public static PasswordSetting GetPasswordSetting()
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/PasswordPolicy.xml"));

        PasswordSetting passwordSetting = new PasswordSetting();

        foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.ChildNodes)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode node2 in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                passwordSetting.Duration = int.Parse(node2["duration"].InnerText);
                passwordSetting.MinLength = int.Parse(node2["minLength"].InnerText);
                passwordSetting.MaxLength = int.Parse(node2["maxLength"].InnerText);
                passwordSetting.NumsLength = int.Parse(node2["numsLength"].InnerText);
                passwordSetting.SpecialLength = int.Parse(node2["specialLength"].InnerText);
                passwordSetting.UpperLength = int.Parse(node2["upperLength"].InnerText);
                passwordSetting.SpecialChars = node2["specialChars"].InnerText;
            }
        }
        return passwordSetting;
    }
}
```

But When I use Them in Button click event the following Problem occures.. Why This Happens?? [image]

Comment: IMO this approach to password requirements is dumb. Don't require characters from certain classes, require a certain complexity. And why would one ever add a `MaxLength` to a password?

Comment: I stored all those Password requirements in an Xml file  since I need to change them when administrator wants too change the requirements.

Comment: please update your question posting namespaces of provided classes. Lines of code with `namespace` would be great

Comment: @all: I got it right when I placed Them in the App_Code folder

Answer (score 5):

It looks like `Helper` is *actually* a nested class within `PasswordStreangth` (sic) for some reason. Although `Helper` (as posted) is a public class, my guess is that `PasswordStreangth` is `internal`. Why is `Helper` a nested class anyway?

It's possible that `PasswordStreangth` is your namespace instead, of course - I don't have VS at hand to check whether it would be shown that way in Intellisense. If that's the case, then presumably `Helper` *isn't* actually declared as public in the version you're building against - possibly a change elsewhere in the code, or a stale build?

Comment: @Sudheesh: It doesn't look that way based on Intellisense. So *is* `PasswordStreangth` a class?

Comment: PasswordSettings.. It's a class

Comment: @Sudheesh: I didn't say PasswordSettings, I said PasswordStreangth, as per the Intellisense tooltip.

Comment: @Sudheesh: That's probably just that it's then in the same assembly. You haven't been at all clear about where the code was before. If the classes are *really, really* public, it should always have been fine.